# Error "Model object has no attribute 'get_shape'" - Fine-tuning Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I am trying to fine-tune the VGG16 model for a dataset with different classes.  Following [this example](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16), I tried to do it like this:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

pretrained = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
model = pretrained.output

# Add new layers here

model = Model(inputs=pretrained.input, outputs=model)
```

However, I'm having trouble adding new layers to the model. Following the line `model = pretrained.output`, I have tried each of the following lines (one at a time):

```
model = Flatten()(pretrained)

model = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(pretrained)

model = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(model)

model = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)(model)  

model = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
```

For the first two lines I tried, I got the error

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

When I tried each of the last three lines, each time I got an error relating to the size of the layer, e.g. the line `model = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)(model)` gave me:

```
Error when checking target: expected conv2d_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (38, 100)
```

How do I fix these errors?  And more generally, how can I know which types of layers I can append to a convolutional model?

Answer (score 0):

After you have added this layer:

```
model = Flatten()(pretrained)
```

your model has become "flat" and has acquired a dimension `[None, X]` - where `X` is the total number of neurons that are contained in the previous layer `pretrained.output`.

That's why obviously after this,  you can't apply convolution and pooling layers just because the shape of your model isn't "square" (like `(None,3,28,20)` for example). In order for everything to work well, you need to determine the output dimension of the `pretrained.output` and then, without `Flatten()` layer, apply the operations of convolution or pooling with necessary sizes of kernels and so on.